# Swift unable to parse string date to Date object

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, swift3, nsdateformatter

I have the following date format:

```
2016-08-26T05:16:50.200Z
```

And I am trying to parse similar date formatted strings into `Date` objects in Swift 3.0.

Here is my effort:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd EEEEE HH:mm:ss Z"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "us")

var date = formatter.date(from: date_str)!
```

Where `date_str` is of the format mentioned above.
Unfortunately, swift don't recognize the format and returns nil.

Note: I don't want to change the string to match the formatter, but to adapt the formatter to the format of the string. String is of external source so I don't have the ability to change the string's format, but to stick with it and create a formatter that will recognize the string's date pattern.

Any ideas on where my format is wrong?

Comment: Maybe stupid question but have you tried to remove spaces so the string exactly matches format?
"yyyy-mm-dd EEEEE HH:mm:ss Z" -> "yyyy-mm-ddEEEEEHH:mm:ssZ"

Comment: @ZassX thanks. I think I have tried, but not the Z at the end. Let me try.

Comment: @ZassX No that didn't worked. To be honest, when I was reading the documentation about the possible values of the formatter, Z wasn't available and I don't know either what that means in a real world date.

Comment: I have tried using online formatter.
This worked OK for me, but that means that date string was a bit different:
2016-08-26T05:16:50-0200
I think that Z in string is not supposed to be there. Also check by yourself: http://nsdateformatter.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making mistake here, Here `T` is not for Week detail, The `T` is just a marker for where the time part begins.

> A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete date expression, the letter T as a delimiter, and a valid time expression. For example "2016-10-05T14:30".

So now just change your `dateFomat` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` and you will get correct date you want.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "us")
var date = formatter.date(from: date_str)!
print(date)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome mate :)